# Adding to ManyToMany Django; no such column error

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to add to a Twitter Clone app I am making using Django (I am new to Django), and I am unable to add new objects to my "following" list because I get "no such column: twitterclone_userpro_following.otherprofile_id". In the ManyToMany Django information page, it appears as easy as using the add command. The following are the two classes and the code I am trying to use to add:

```
class OtherProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def get_username(self):
    return username

class UserPro(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(OtherProfile)
```

And the following is the code I am trying to use to add to the following column:

```
me = UserPro.objects.get(username="newuser1")
himher = OtherProfile.objects.get(username="newuser2")
me.following.add(himher)
```

I don't understand the advice most answers online have, which involves using South, and I assume there must be an easy way without it, because the Many-To-Many documentation does not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known django issue if you create your models, run `syncdb` and then add a `ManyToManyField` on one of your models. In this situation running `syncdb` again wouldn't help - it wouldn't pick and apply your model changes, see:

- [Django - syncdb doesn't create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016064/django-syncdb-doesnt-create-tables)
- [Adding a ManyToManyField field to an existing model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264585/adding-a-manytomanyfield-field-to-an-existing-model?lq=1)

The best way to go is to start using [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest) - it can track your model changes and apply them through the schema and data migrations mechanism. It's worth trying.

Just FYI, you can also create that necessary many-to-many table manually.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you! I installed south using easy_install, but now am running into "ImportError: No module named twitterclonesouth". Any idea how to combat this?

Comment: @user3404392 that's a strange error. Do you have `south` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes. I put it in my installed apps. When I remove it, that issue goes away

Comment: @user3404392 the module name `twitterclonesouth` is very strange..have you followed [installation instructions](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)?