# Django syncdb doesn't create tables from app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-syncdb

I am learning and it might be just stupid mistake, but `syncdb` and `migrate` creates all admin tables, but no my app tables so only Groups and Users works in admin panel. I see my models in admin panel, but when I try to enter them it gives me an error `Table 'baza63843_django.testowa_news' doesn't exist`.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nazwa Kategorii', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Odnośnik', unique=True, max_length=100)
    icon = models.ImageField('Ikonka Kategorii', upload_to='icons',
                              blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kategoria"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kategorie"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Tytuł', max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField('Odnośnik', max_length=255, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Treść')
    #categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Kategoria")
    #categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Kategorie')
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField('Data dodania', auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Wiadomość"
        verbose_name_plural = "Wiadomości"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

At the beginning I made here ManyToManyField, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016064/django-syncdb-doesnt-create-tables) I changed it. But still doesn't work.

I have my app in `settings.py`, it is called `testowa`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    #'bootstrap_admin', # always before django.contrib.admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    'testowa',
)
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create migrations first:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

After that run migrate command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Srsly, facepalm. I couldn't find that info in few tutorials. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django 1.7 please follow the following commands to get the tables created in the db.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

after that command run the following command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

As south database migrations are inbuild with Django 1.7